# Mysql DB not updating correctly

Tags: php, mysql

I'm sure im missing something very simple I have run mysql update scripts many times but this one wont work and I cant understand why.
I'm calling data from a DB into a ckeditor text box when the update button is clicked this script runs I get success messages but the DB doesn't update what am I missing???

```
session_start();
include ("mysql-connect.php");
include ("check-login.php");
if(isset($_POST['editblogbody'])){
      if($_POST['editblogbody'] != "" && $_POST['editblogtitle'] != "" && $_POST['blog_id'] != ""){
          $title = $_POST['editblogtitle'];
          $body = $_POST['editblogbody'];
          $bid = $_POST['blog_id'];
          $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE blogs SET title='$title', body='$body' WHERE id='$bid'")or die (mysql_error());    
          echo '<img src="../_Images/round_success.png" alt="Success" width="31" height="30" />Success 1';  
          exit();            
      }
      else{
          echo '<img src="../_Images/round_success.png" alt="Success" width="31" height="30" />Success 2';  
          exit();
      }
}
else{
    echo '<img src="../_Images/round_error.png" alt="Error" width="31" height="30" /> &nbsp; Opps something went wrong. Please Try again.'; 
    exit();
}
```

The script thats post the form

```
$('#editblog').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('input[type=submit]', this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    var blogTitle = $("#editblogtitle").val();
    var blogText = CKEDITOR.instances['editblogbody'].getData();
    var url = "../_Scripts/edit-blog.php";
    if (!blogTitle) {
        $('input[type=submit]', this).removeAttr('disabled');
        $("#blogeditreply").html('<img src="../_Images/round_error.png" alt="Error" width="31" height="30" /> &nbsp; Please type a Title.').show().fadeOut(6000);
        return false;
    } else if (!blogText) {
        $('input[type=submit]', this).removeAttr('disabled');
        $("#blogeditreply").html('<img src="../_Images/round_error.png" alt="Error" width="31" height="30" /> &nbsp; Please type in your Blog.').show().fadeOut(6000);
        return false;
    } else {
        $("#blogFormProcessGif").show();
        for (instance in CKEDITOR.instances) {
            CKEDITOR.instances['blogbody'].updateElement();
        }
        $.post(url, $('#editblog').serialize(), function (data) {
            $("#jqueryReply").html(data).show().fadeOut(6000);
            $("#blogFormProcessGif").hide();
            $.modal.close();
        });
    }
});
```

connection loos like so

```
define('HOSTNAME','#'); 
define('DB_USERNAME','#'); 
define('DB_PASSWORD','#');
define('DATABASE','#'); 
$link = mysql_connect(constant('HOSTNAME'), constant('DB_USERNAME'), constant('DB_PASSWORD')) or die("Database connection error, please check!"); mysql_select_db(constant('DATABASE'), $link) or die("Connection to the defined database not possible, please check!");
```

I can echo out all the varibles fine so all the info is there

Thanks

Comment: And you're connected to both DB and table?

Comment: If your `id` column is an `INT` then try changing `WHERE id='$bid'` to `WHERE id=$bid` without quotes.

Comment: Please use mysql_real_escape_string to escape all the post fields, otherwise you will get errors as soon as there is a quote mark in the text. $body = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['editblogbody']);

Comment: What does your DB connection look like, are you using `$con` or something similar as a DB connection variable? @Benjio if so, then you may need to use `WHERE id='$bid'", $con)`

Comment: Maybe echo $sql, and check the blog id is correct, as everything else looks like it should work

Comment: I have updated above to show what connection im using.

Comment: You may need to add `$link` as in `...WHERE id='$bid'", $link)` for your query. @Benjio that's what I'm betting on. You're not checking for DB insert errors, only your initial connection. Try that, pretty sure that may be the problem.

Comment: @bumperbox the id is correct :/

Comment: My connection works fine i have queryed my DB many time in the website im creating using the same connection and the similar sql query

Comment: Ok, but did you "try" my suggestion? @Benjio

Comment: Yep i get a mysql error "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' Resource id #4' at line 1" @Fred -ii-

Comment: And you always used `constant` for your DB connection `$link = mysql_connect(constant('HOSTNAME')...`? I don't know why you're using that, but if that's the first time you do, then try removing them (to test). When an error as such appears, it's obvious there's a syntax error somewhere and that's why it's not updating your DB. @Benjio

Comment: Ok i have worked out whats causing the problem but cant work out how to fix it. its the text within the ckeditor text area it posting the original text not the edited text so i think its updating but the same content. its the var blogText = CKEDITOR.instances['editblogbody'].getData(); line

Comment: JS is not one of my strong points, so I can't help you there. @Benjio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed something very simple sorry everyone :(

```
$('#editblog').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('input[type=submit]', this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    var blogTitle = $("#editblogtitle").val();
    var blogText = CKEDITOR.instances['editblogbody'].getData();
    var url = "../_Scripts/edit-blog.php";
    if (!blogTitle) {
        $('input[type=submit]', this).removeAttr('disabled');
        $("#blogeditreply").html('<img src="../_Images/round_error.png" alt="Error" width="31" height="30" /> &nbsp; Please type a Title.').show().fadeOut(6000);
        return false;
    } else if (!blogText) {
        $('input[type=submit]', this).removeAttr('disabled');
        $("#blogeditreply").html('<img src="../_Images/round_error.png" alt="Error" width="31" height="30" /> &nbsp; Please type in your Blog.').show().fadeOut(6000);
        return false;
    } else {
        $("#blogFormProcessGif").show();
        for (instance in CKEDITOR.instances) {
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////Forgot to change the editor instance here/////////////////////
            CKEDITOR.instances['blogbody'].updateElement();
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        }
        $.post(url, $('#editblog').serialize(), function (data) {
            $("#jqueryReply").html(data).show().fadeOut(6000);
            $("#blogFormProcessGif").hide();
            $.modal.close();
        });
    }
});
```

Sorry put a comment in the code. I forgot to change the ckeditor instance at the bottom of the script

Comment: So you fixed it then, what was it exactly, you only posted code, but not what the error itself was.

Answer (score 0):

Which Success-Answer do you get?
"Success 1" or "Success 2"

Comment: this should be a comment, not an answer

Comment: i get Success 1 mate :)